# Images not serving (for sites that use a subdomain)

Tags: images, nginx

I am using docker-compose to host 5 wordpress sites on a vps vm (ubuntu).

My site hosts and shows images just fine, but the other 4 (my kids) can’t serve images. Each site has it's own public_html directory, but they all access the same MariaDB. I can upload images just fine, but the direct url link to the images is 404. When I check on the server, the files have the correct permissions and formatted in various sizes. The nginx configs are the same for all the sites. The only difference is that the non-working sites have a subdomain a record in DNS (mykid.thepage.com) vs https://www.thepage.com. I’ve reviewed all the logs (nginx, wordpress) and can’t see why the images won’t serve. I have no plugins and have tried multiple themes.

I would love to know anything I can try? The basic test is the direct access url which returns a 404 even though the image is in the right place.

Only one image shows: https://ellie.theboohers.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/butterfly-icon.jpg

The others cause 404s: https://ellie.theboohers.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/TEDSUE-e1688271451859.jpg

I realized I asked this 6 months ago and I couldn't get any help then, link:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/intermittent-404s-for-images/

site info: https://gist.github.com/tbbooher/8423951a70326b53c4eb16e2c85ab8e9

Comment: Serving an image shouldn't go through WordPress though. Is the server block definitely set up correctly for the subdomain, for the path with the right wp-content folder?

Comment: (And in some multisite configurations I think WP puts the side ID into the content URL: that's not the issue here, the path on disk is correct?)

Comment: this is interesting, I have two files with teh same permissions. one is just a copy of the other. one displays, the other doesn't: 
deploy@cromwell:/srv/rufus/ellie_public_html/wp-content/uploads/2022/12$ curl -L -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://ellie.theboohers.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/butterfly-icon-150x150.jpg
200

deploy@cromwell:/srv/rufus/ellie_public_html/wp-content/uploads/2022/12$ curl -L -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://ellie.theboohers.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/foo.jpg
404